# Why am I being asked for credentials

Tags: email, powershell

I would like to ask for advise why this script is asking me for credentials.

After running the script, a powershell window opens and another window asking for login and password. After I give this login and password it works (mail is sent) but I want it to work automatically.

Here is the code:

```
$pw = Get-Content C:\path\passwordfile.txt 
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "mymail", $pw
Send-MailMessage -from "Test <mymail>" -to "recipient <recipientmail>" -Subject  "Script Test" -body "Script Test" -priority high -smtpserver poczta.o2.pl -credential $cred
SmtpServer=mysmtpadress
SmtpPort=465
```

Comment: For increased security look into using get-credential to create an clixml file that contains an encrypted form of the password. It won't hold up against someone who has compromised your machine but definitely better than plain text.

Answer (score 2):

The [`PSCredential` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms567279(v=vs.85).aspx) accepts the username as a string, but expects the password to be a `SecureString`:

```
$pw = Get-Content C:\path\passwordfile.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
```

Comment: I will add that if you plan to keep your password in a plain text file anyway, you should: a) Just put the password right there in the script and b) Just go ahead and change it to "password" since it has lost any value whatsoever as a security device at this point.